# How to password protect terms in Taxonomy

Tags: users

I have a taxonomy vocab "region"
in the region, I have a bunch of provinces as the terms, and subpages for each province.

I would like to add a password protect or only allow authorized users to access the provinces.

etc, only username "ontario" "password" can access the term "ontario" in the taxonomy. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

These modules may help, for D7 & D8 on DEV version is [Taxonomy Access Control Lite](https://www.drupal.org/project/tac_lite), on approved versions (recommended): D7 is [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) and for D8 is [Permissions by Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term), review wich one fit best your needs.